# php variable that points to another variable

Tags: php, class, variables

Was wondering if it's possible to have a variable point to another variable in PHP? What I'm trying to do is to have a class instance like:

```
$users = new User_Model();
```

and then have

```
$user
```

simply point to

```
$users
```

instead of making a new class instance. Is this possible? Think I saw something about it in the php manual, but cant find it again.

Would

```
$users = new User_Model();
$user = $users;
```

simply do it?

Thanks

Comment: lol. Wormhole. I *wish* they were called that instead of references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default in PHP 5 objects are copied by reference. So when you do

```
$users = new User_Model();
$user = $users;
```

Both $user and $users point to the same object.

However primitive types are still passed by value

```
$va = 1;
$vb = $va;
$va = 2;
echo $vb; //1
```

So you need to take the reference of the primitive value;

```
$va = 1;
$vb = &$va;
$va = 2;
echo $vb; //2
```

Answer (score 1):

$user = &$users;

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php